# How to construct the data frame such that the "species" column has the actual species names (setosa etc)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
import sklearn.datasets as data
iris = data.load_iris()
import pandas as pd
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns=iris['feature_names'])

iris_df['species'] = iris['filename']
iris_df
```

in species name there's iris.csv showing but i need actual species names (setosa etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with list comprehensions:

Replace the last 2-lines with:

```py
iris_df['species'] = iris['target'] 
    #species column is filled with 0,1,2 (class indexes)
iris_df['species'] = iris_df['species'].replace({i:k for i,k in enumerate(iris['target_names'])}) 
    #here we replace the indexes with strings
    # 0 replaced with 'setosa', 1 with 'versicolor'
```

output would be:

```
   sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  ...  petal width (cm)    species
0                  5.1               3.5  ...               0.2     setosa
1                  4.9               3.0  ...               0.2     setosa
2                  4.7               3.2  ...               0.2     setosa
3                  4.6               3.1  ...               0.2     setosa
4                  5.0               3.6  ...               0.2     setosa
..                 ...               ...  ...               ...        ...
145                6.7               3.0  ...               2.3  virginica
146                6.3               2.5  ...               1.9  virginica
147                6.5               3.0  ...               2.0  virginica
148                6.2               3.4  ...               2.3  virginica
149                5.9               3.0  ...               1.8  virginica
```